# Execute Powershell code on remote computer and then use result on local computer

Tags: powershell, jenkins, remote-access, scriptblock

I know, that to execute code on remote computer, I must use -ArgumentList and param to pass variables to remote host.

Can anyone hint me, how to execute code on remote computer, and then use result on local computer?

My code, to determine free space on remote computer, and, depending on result - fail build, if remote host has not enough space:

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:password -AsPlainText -force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("$env:login",$securePassword)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:SERVER -credential $credential -scriptblock {
$freespace = Get-PSDrive D
echo $freespace.Free
$DiskDSpace = ($freespace.Free) 
If ($DiskDSpace -lt 214748364809999999999999) { 
    echo "Free space on disk D is less than 20 GB" 
    $LastExitCode = 1
    exit $LastExitCode 
    }
}
```

Problem, is that `$DiskDSpace` variable value only present on remote computer and Jenkins fails build only, if  `"$LastExitCode = 1"` & `"exit $LastExitCode"` executed outside `"-scriptblock {"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$diskSpace = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:SERVER -credential $credential -scriptblock {
$freespace = Get-PSDrive D
echo $freespace.Free
$DiskDSpace = ($freespace.Free) 
If ($DiskDSpace -lt 214748364809999999999999) { 
    echo "Free space on disk D is less than 20 GB" 
    $LastExitCode = 1
    exit $LastExitCode 
    }
}
```

Note the $diskSpace before the Invoke-Command. This should do the trick!